# Auctex preview does not adjust line color of fractions

Tags: auctex, preview-latex

I am using `auctex` to preview latex fragments (in the normal latex mode as well as in org-mode using `texfrag`).

I am using a dark theme, so I rely on `auctex` to convert the foreground color from black to the one set in my theme. This does work for normal text. But in fractions, the fraction line itself is still black (the denominator and numerator are converted fine).

Does someone have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: You might want to submit a bug report using `M-x TeX-submit-bug-report <RET>`.

Comment: Thanks for the info @NickD. I submitted a bug report.